# Make ClassData pick first n elements from IEnumerable<object[]>

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit

Given the following mock data in a xUnit tests project

```
public sealed class MockData : IEnumerable<object[]>
{
    public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return new object[] { "First", 1 };
        yield return new object[] { "Second", 2 };
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

I want to use that class for two tests

```
[Theory]
[ClassData(typeof(MockData))]
private void FirstTest(string foo)
{
    Assert.True(true);
}
    
[Theory]
[ClassData(typeof(MockData))]
private void SecondTest(string foo, int bar)
{
    Assert.True(true);
}
```

but as you can see the first test only takes in one parameter. When running the tests the first one fails with this exception

> System.InvalidOperationException: The test method expected 1 parameter
> value, but 2 parameter values were provided.

Is there a way I can make the `ClassData` pick the first column from that object and ignore the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this. A few solutions I can think of:

---

**Use MemberData**

```
[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(MockData.ColumnA), MemberType= typeof(MockData))]
private void ColATest(string foo) => ...

[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(MockData.ColumnB), MemberType= typeof(MockData))]
private void ColBTest(string foo) => ...

[Theory]
[ClassData(typeof(MockData))]
private void SecondTest(string foo, int bar)
{
   Assert.True(true);
}

public sealed class MockData : IEnumerable<object[]>
{
    public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return new object[] { "First", 1 };
        yield return new object[] { "Second", 2 };
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> ColumnA => this.Select(x => x[0]);
    public IEnumerable<int> ColumnB => this.Select(x => x[1]);

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

---

**Add a parameter to the method and ignore it:**

```
[Theory]
[ClassData(typeof(MockData))]
private void FirstTest(string foo, int bar)
{
    // just don't use 'bar'
    Assert.True(true);
}
    
[Theory]
[ClassData(typeof(MockData))]
private void SecondTest(string foo, int bar)
{
    Assert.True(true);
}
```

Comment: hmm maybe one data class could provide the first values and a second data class merges the values from data class one with its own values? So the second data class extends the first one?

Comment: Yes, you could do that. Or the other way around. Make a class that provides all data, and two other classes wrap around this and provide column A and column B respectively.